# What is the formula in .NET for "*" (wildcard) version numbers?

Tags: .net, versioning, assemblyversionattribute

Say I have a version number 1.5.* that is compiled as 1.5.4735.28467.

What is the formula for getting 4735 and 28467?

Comment: major, minor, build, revision.  Build and revision are up to you....

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jensenh/archive/2005/11/11/491779.aspx.  But that's for Microsoft Office; I don't know if it works the same way for the .NET Framework.

Comment: Build = DateTime.Today.Subtract(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1)).Days; Revision = (int)DateTime.Now.Subtract(DateTime.Today).TotalSeconds / 2;
Too bad this got closed; the alleged duplicate is a different question...

Comment: @Daniel: Is that for the .NET Framework?  Do you have a reference?

Comment: This is what the C# compiler uses when you use [AssemblyVersion("1.5.*")].
I'm not sure if other .NET languages do the same.
I can't find any documentation for this; I just compiled something and checked that the numbers match. I don't know where I was remembering the formula from.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Please note:** there are *alternative tools/rules/schemes/macros/add-ins/etc* to control versioning in a different manner; if used they obviously obliterate the following.

However, this is how a `"*"` version is calculated to `.build.revision` in a *vanilla* Visual Studio / .NET build process:

> When specifying a version, you have to at least specify major. If you specify major and minor, you *can specify an asterisk (*) for build*. This will cause ***build* to be equal to the number of days since January 1, 2000 local time**, and for ***revision* to be equal to the number of seconds since midnight local time, divided by 2.**

See [Coding Horror: Determining Build Date the hard way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/determining-build-date-the-hard-way.html) and [MSDN: AssemblyVersionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.assemblyversionattribute.aspx). This default expansion behavior is documented in the AssemblyVersionAttribute class (BCL!) <del>and not special VS compiler behavior</del> (see Daniel's comment) and not exclusively compiler behavior.

---

Here is one implementation of the formula (as extracted from Daniel's comment):

```
int Build = DateTime.Today.Subtract(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1)).Days;
int Revision = (int)DateTime.Now.Subtract(DateTime.Today).TotalSeconds / 2;
```

Comment: It's most definitely compiler behavior. The compiler doesn't instantiate any attributes; it just encodes the argument values in metadata. But the number gets substituted at compile-time; it must be a special case in the compiler. There's no way to write your a custom attribute to do something similar.

Comment: @Daniel That is a good argument. I wish I could find a VS (not .NET) reference on how version numbers worked.

Comment: You can also see the implementation in Roslyn: http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/VersionHelper.cs,95